# add data to my Json in django

Tags: json, django

This is how my JSON data looks like

`{"id": 50, "first_digit": "2", "second_digit": "1", "calculate": "Addition"}`

I want to add extra data `"result":"3"` to my JSON

> this is my view

```
def calc(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    first_number = request.POST['first number']
    second_number = request.POST['second number']
    operation = request.POST['operation']

    result = do_calc(operation, first_number, second_number)
                                # how to pass the result to my tempelate
    value = Calculation.objects.create(
        first_digit=first_number,
        second_digit=second_number,
        calculate=operation
    )
    data = model_to_dict(value)

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Can anyone help me with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably the output of `model_to_dict()` is a dict. So you can simply add your value to that dict:

```
data = model_to_dict(value)
data['result'] = result
return JsonResponse(data)
```